# How to view HPA autoscaling definition in GKE console

Tags: google-kubernetes-engine, autoscaling, hpa, horizontal-pod-autoscaling

Using GKE version - 1.18.17-gke.700

I am looking to find an option inside GKE console, where I can find the information of Pods HPA autoscalling information?
We are able to get the HPA info using "kubectl get hpa -n <> " but trying to know how one can get this info from GKE console who don't want to use kubectl . I tried looking at Pod & Replicaset YAML configuration in GKE console, but I am unable to find the HPA specifications.

I tried exploring many articles(sample article link below), nothing really shows us an answer...Options whatever has been shared over forums are not available currently.

https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/horizontal-pod-autoscaling

Can someone please advise?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On the left menu, click Workloads, then select a workload and choose Actions>>Autoscale on the top menu.

[image: Autoscale addition]

From here you can add your criteria and max pod limit.

Once you save, you can see your changes reflected in the workload overview page, all the way at the bottom.

[image: Results]

Comment: Thanks Nick for the response.. Can I know what GKE version you are trying? Ya I am aware of this option but on the GKE version - 1.18.17-gke.700 which I am using, I don't see Autoscale option under Actions. Is Autoscale option disabled after any GKE versions?

Comment: No problem! This should be available from v.1.18: https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/run-application/horizontal-pod-autoscale/#support-for-configurable-scaling-behavior, you might want to try upgrading the API, and also I'm not sure if this works with an autopilot cluster:
https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/concepts/cluster-upgrades

Comment: You're right! I meant to paste the one that focuses on the controlplane. https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/upgrading-a-cluster. But now I'm curious why you don't see the option. Is this an autopilot cluster?

Comment: Guess it is not an autopilot cluster, as we manage the nodes and upgrades.. Tried looking to know the type of my cluster but unable to find it...Cna you please share how i can verify my cluster type?.. Also login id  is synced to an AD group - not sure whether privilege's are blocked to view Auto Cluster option .. Any way I can confirm whether due to role/permission this option is blocked?

Comment: Any further suggestions on this please?

Comment: @Surendar you can check your cluster type by the `Mode` column in `Kubernetes Engine` -> `Clusters`. It should show it's either a standard or autopilot one. Could you please confirm that you are having an actively running `HPA` resource that is referencing your `Deployment` and you can see it in the `kubectl get hpa ...` but you cannot see it in the Cloud Console?

Comment: It is an standard cluster,i couldn't find mode option in my cluster but when i did "kubectl describe cluster",i dont find "autopilot: enabled: true".

Comment: Hi All - Can someone help here?

Comment: Thanks Dawik - For workloads which got deployed using "Type:ReplicaSet" we dont see the autoscale option but for workloads with Type:Deployment we are able to see the autoscale option in console